# Could not find a part of the path xamarin

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

```
Error   2   The "CreateAdditionalLibraryResourceCache" task failed   unexpectedly.
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Srinivasarao\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.2.1.0\embedded'.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String  originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.CreateAdditionalLibraryResourceCache.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()    test
```

i Copied the project from  other system and tried to build in my visual studio but it throws the above error.
The path shown in the above error refers to the system from where i have copied.

can you please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the required library is either missing or corrupted. Are you able to take the following steps:

1. Open Windows Explorer
2. Navigate to C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\
3. Delete the folders that match
   C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin.*
4. Delete C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips
5. Clean Solution
6. Attempt build again

Thanks!